# Convert this LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout created by using nested `LinearLayout`s.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="foo1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="foo_value"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="foo2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="foo2_value"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

This gives the following:

[image]

a) How can I convert this layout to using a `RelativeLayout` and achieve the same result?
I have tried the following:

```
<RelativeLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo_value"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/id1"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo2"
        android:layout_below="@id/id1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo2_value"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/id2"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_1"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but the result is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

b) How could I convert to a `ConstraintLayout`? What should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a) RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/id_1"
    android:text="foo1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="foo_value" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/id1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/id_2"
    android:text="foo2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="foo2_value" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**b) ConstraintLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="foo1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="foo_value"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="foo2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="foo2_value"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: When I add `android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/id_1"` everything disappears

Comment: Also you are using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in the `TextView`

Comment: Also I copy/pasted the `ConstraintLayout` and it is not aligned at all

Comment: @Jim Try pasting the complete snippet for `ConstraintLayout` and `RelativeLayout` in a separate layout file. I have edited them as complete XML and also changed TextView back to wrap_content.

Comment: So the solution is to align the first to start of the second for the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @Jim yes, that's correct.

Comment: For the `ConstraintLayout` how come is the `TextView` with `id_2` set with `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id1"` instead of `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_1". It works as you have defined it, but I would have expected to be bellow the other textview

Comment: Yes, we can do that as well as both `id1 ` and `id_1 ` lies at the same horizontal level.

Comment: @Jim Kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem.